# I want to add a value in a database table (particular column only not all column) how can I do it?

Tags: php, forms

table has following column,
id , name, address, phone, city
all information except city is filled with normal php form, now I want to fill column "city" with dropdown option.

```
<select id="dropdown" name="cityName">
    <option value="NewYork">New York</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>      
    <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is your question about how to interpret the result of a form being submitted that contains that select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to answer without seeing any other code but here is something generic using PDO and a prepared statement for the PHP side of things. You, of course, need to submit the select field values to your server from the html page either by form action or ajax with JavaScript. I recommend keeping your database config values in it's own file and including it in the separate file that will  perform the database update query.

```
<?php

// It's recommended to keep these config values in their own file but including it here for reference
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "yourdatabaseusername";
$password = "youpassword";
$databasename = "databasename";

// Set up the database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$databasename", $username, $password);

// Set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Set variables for city name from the form and an id of the row you'd like to update
$city = $_POST['cityName'];
$id = 'valueforid';

// If there is a value for city, try to do the DB update
if (isset($city)) {

    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tablename SET city = :city WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':city' => $city, ':id' => $id));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;

}
?>
```

This is purely an example, you need to tailor this to your unique set-up and server configuration since this is using PDO. Additionally you need to update the table name to the table's name in your database. Lastly, sanitize data etc from the POST before even entering it in the DB.

Hope this gets you on the right track.